# crontab-ui give me an error running external script not directly executed

Tags: docker, cron

I've imported all cron job my crontab-ui (https://github.com/alseambusher/crontab-ui).

I got one executable into this directory:/etc/periodic/daily (one of default present in Alpine Linux).The "do-ntp" file has all permission and exists in that directory, I'm sure!

```
run-parts: can't execute '/etc/periodic/daily/do-ntp': No such file or directory


/crontab-ui # cd /etc/periodic/daily/
/etc/periodic/daily # ls -lh
total 4K     
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          43 May 13 01:13 do-ntp
```

Error seems something related to an external execution outside crontab-ui?
Scheduling directly... it runs successful without passing through /etc/periodic/... folder

the file is very simple

```
#!/bin/sh
ntpd -d -q -n -p uk.pool.ntp.org
```

Is it correct?
ALEN